# Late value assigning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm building a quiz app. I need the user to try again if he answered wrong and alter him that his answer is wrong. But whenever i click on the right answer the alter("Wrong") will work and on the second click (whether it's right or wrong) alter("Right") will work.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Questions } from "../Data/Questions";
import "../App.css";
import { QuizContext } from "../Context";

export default function Quiz() {
  const { score, setScore, setGameState } = useContext(QuizContext);

  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");

  const NextQuestion = () => {
    if (Questions[currentQuestion].Answer === selectedAnswer) {
      setScore(score + 1);
      setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)
    } else { 
      alert("Try again! That was wrong")   
    }
    
  };

  const FinishQuiz = () => { 
    if (Questions[currentQuestion].Answer === selectedAnswer) {
      setScore(score + 1);
    }
    setGameState("endScreen")

  };

  const handleAnswer =() => { 
    if (Questions[currentQuestion].Answer === selectedAnswer){
      alert("Good")
    } else { 
      alert("Wrong")
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="QuizScreen">
      <h1>{Questions[currentQuestion].question} </h1>
      <div className="options">
        <button
          onClick={Event => { 
            setSelectedAnswer("optionA");
            handleAnswer();
          }}
        >
          
          <span className="Letter">A. </span>
          <img
            src={Questions[currentQuestion].optionA}
            width={110}
            height={100}
            alt="Option A"
          />
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={Event => { 
            setSelectedAnswer("optionB");
            handleAnswer();
          }}
        >
          
          <span className="Letter">B. </span>
          <img
            src={Questions[currentQuestion].optionB}
            width={110}
            height={100}
            alt="Option B"
          />
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={Event => { 
            setSelectedAnswer("optionC");
            handleAnswer();
          }}
        >
          
          <span className="Letter">C. </span>
          <img
            src={Questions[currentQuestion].optionC}
            width={110}
            height={100}
            alt="Option C"
          />
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={Event => { 
            setSelectedAnswer("optionD");
            console.log("GG")
            handleAnswer();
          }}
        >
          
          <span className="Letter">D. </span>
          <img
            src={Questions[currentQuestion].optionD}
            width={110}
            height={100}
            alt="Option D"
          />
        </button>
      </div>
      {currentQuestion === Questions.length - 1 ? (
        <button className="FinishBtn" onClick={FinishQuiz}> Finish Quiz</button>
      ): ( 
        <button className="NextBtn" onClick={NextQuestion}> Next Question!</button>
        )}
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

I didn't know what to do i traced the code so many times and can't figure out why there's like a latency in assigning the value or checking it.

Comment: When you call `setSelectedAnswer` that queues a state update.  You then immediately call `handleAnswer` and expect that state to already be updated, which it isn't.  One approach would be to pass the value needed to `handleAnswer` instead of reading that value from state.  The linked duplicate has more information and approaches.